# Compare to constant problems

Tags: matlab, simulink

New to simulink, I'm tracking two sine signals and want to single out the moments when one of them hits 0.7, but on the rise. The problem I am having is that the compare to constant only confirms the first "hit" and none of the subsequent ones. If I put >0.7 in the box, it correctly confirms every pass over the 0.7 value. What gives?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You shouldn't do an equality test on double precision floating point number, but rather compare the difference (or absolute value of the difference) to some small tolerance value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a triggered subsystem with a value reset inside. I do not have the time right now to provide a scheme but I will do it if you do not find the solution in the next few days